# How to test HQL queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, hql, environment

I'm searching for a fast (really fast) way to test changes to hibernate queries. I have a huge application with thousands of different HQL queries (in XML files) and 100+ mapped classes and i dont want to redeploy the whole application to just test one tiny change to a query.

How would a good setup look like to free me from redeployment and enable a fast query check?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With Intellij IDEA 8.1.3 the mechnism of choice is called 'Facet'. To instantly test HQL queries:

1. create a data source Tools -> Data Source, Add Data Source, define driver, username and password of yor development db
2. in case you dont have already a hibernate.cfg or you configure your session factory in a different way than via xml: create a hibernate.cfg file referencing all XML mapping's (define a name for the session factory, just for easier handling)
3. in 'Project Structure' add Facet to your module of choice and assign the recently defined data source to the new facet
4. switch to Java EE View
5. Open Hibernate Facets - Node
6. Right click Session factory and choose "Open HQL Console"
7. enter HQL query in console
   ...and your're done.

sorry for this RTFM question.

Comment: More info about HQL support in IntelliJ is here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/java_hibernate.html

Comment: If you're using netbeans, simply right click on hibernate.cfg.xml, probably sitting in your default package, and select 'Do HQL query'

Comment: Detailed help on the latest version: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/hibernate.html

Answer (score 13):

You can use [hibernate tools in eclipse](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) to run queries.  This will allow you to run HQL whenever you want to try something.

<strike>If you're using IntelliJ, there is [Hibero](http://www.betosoftware.com/hibero/).</strike>

<strike>There is a [standalone editor](https://hqe.dev.java.net/) from sun, but I haven't tried it.</strike>

Comment: does there exist a solution (=plugin, whatever) for IntelliJ IDEA 8?

Comment: yeah, thxn. if it works how they describe it, it's exactly what i need, but: "Since 1 January 2008 .. Hibero™ have been discontinued for business reasons.", so what now?

Comment: I guess I'll delete that bookmark then, haven't used IntelliJ for a while (not a choice, just a budget).

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit the post but the correct url to Hibernate Tools is: http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html

Comment: @stevedbrown : link for standalone editor is broken. Could you update it, please?

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a simple tool to test & preview HQL, this is just one java class with main method.

you can find the code here: https://github.com/maheskrishnan/HQLRunner

here's the screen shot...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I test my HQL queries in unit-tests with the HSQLDB database. Just create an entity manager, cast it to a hibernate session and query away.

```
    final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tacs-test", props);

    final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    return (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();
```

Best
Anders

Answer (score 3):

You said the quickest way, I'm not sure if you meant the quickest way to get going, or the quickest way to perform ongoing tests, with some initial investment to get the tests implemented. This answer is more the latter.

The way I've done this before was to implement some simple integration testing with [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) and [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/).

In essence, you'll be using DBUnit to set up your test database with a known and representative set of data, and then plain JUnit to exercise the methods containing your HQL queries, and verify the results.

For instance,

Set up your database first to contain only a fixed set of data e.g.,

```
Product Name, Price
Acme 100 Series Dynamite, $100
Acme 200 Series Dynamite, $120
Acme Rocket, $500
```

This is something you'd do in your JUnit test case's setup() method.

Now let's assume you have a DAO for this entity, and there's a "findProductWithPriceGreaterThan(int)" method. In your test, you'd do something like:

```
public void testFindProductWithPriceGreaterThanInt() {
    ProductDAO dao = new HibernateProductDAO();
    //... initialize Hibernate, or perhaps do this in setup()

    List products = dao.findProductWithPriceGreaterThan(110);
    assertEquals(2, products.size());
    //... additional assertions to verify the content of the list.
}
```

Comment: with quick/fast i meant the 'change-test-change-test' ... iteration.

Comment: @Chris once you have a base class for DBunit testing, you can write test methods in less than a minute and they run for seconds. Not as fast as a dedicated query editor with a big "run" button, but the good thing about DBUnit tests is that you can save them and use them as regression tests. I personally am using Eclipse Hibernate Tools for initial try'n'error and DBUnit once it works.

Answer (score 2):

In the eclipse Market, you can search for JBoss Tools and choose only Hibernate tools from the given list.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse

1. Install Hibernate tools(Jboss)
2. Switch to hibernate perpective
3. Open/click Hibernate Configuration window
4. Rt Click on the window and Add Configuration
5. Rt Click on the window click/open HQL editor
6. Type and execute your HQL queries and get your result in the Hibernate Query result window

Follow this link for more info http://docs.jboss.org/tools/OLD/2.0.0.GA/hibernatetools/en/html/plugins.html