# How can I test Hibernate HQL Queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, hql

SQL queries can be simulated very easy with almost every sql database viewer. Is there an equivalent to HQL queries? Is there a viewer where I can view the results of a HQL query or simulate it?

I have seen this Post: [How to test HQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043554/how-to-test-hql-queries), but it is from 2009 so there might be something new now?

Is there some plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, I suggest Hibernate Tools 3.4.x

Here the link (simply drag "Install" on your already open Eclipse):
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hibernate-tools-0