# Tool to test HQL queries - Hibernate+Spring+Annotations+Maven

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, hql

Is there a way to test HQL queries from Hibernate project integrated with Spring?

I came across JBoss tools for eclipse, but unable to configure it as it is expecting hibernate.cfg.xml file as input, whereas we had all our configuration in hibernateContext.xml file and annotations were used instead of .hbm files.

Any ideas please?

Comment: this problem can be solved at this link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043554/how-to-test-hql-queries

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Will the solution works with annotation based configuration as well? If yes, where should I specify the list of my annotated classes, which contains all the mappings.